# How does this $3\times 3$ rotation matrix come from the $2\times 2$ rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

According to Wikipedia the 2x2 rotation matrix is submatrix of the 3x3 rotation matrix

[image]

However if you look at the 3x3 rotation matrices

[image]

How is Qy made?

Comment: Submatrix $\neq$ subset of matrix.

Comment: Submatrix $\ne$ **subblock**. The first is obtained by cancelling certain row(s) and column(s). The second one preserves *consecutive* lines and columns